# Android Activity, how to override manifest's android:configChanges with Java code?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I'm coding a custom Activity class (using it as a super class for my other Activity classes) where it's overriding many default functionalities. One of these functionalities I want is orientation handling, and while I can do it, it requires

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the manifest. Is there a way to enforce the same thing as the line above, but in java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll still need to include the attribute in the XML but you can handle it in Java too; see my blog post here: http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/dealing-with-screen-orientation-changes-manually/

Edit: You cannot set the configChanges attribute programmatically. I guess it's to do with the way an Activity is created. They're created from the XML first and then the overridden methods in your activity implementation are invoked. There's nothing in the API that lets you change the configChanges attribute.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not asking how to do code to actually handle the orientation, but instead wondering where android:configChanges is read and then set in the Activity's life. If it's even possible, at least.

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood, I've amended my original post.

Comment: I think you may be right, C0deAttack. I'll leave the question open for a bit and if nobody comes up with a solution I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Any one get the answer?

Comment: The link is not working anymore

Comment: I too am looking for something that lets me change the configChanges attribute programmatically, but couldn't come up with anything yet. I guess it's not yet possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all possible value in "android:configChanges",and override method **onConfigurationChanged** in Activity,but only call **Activity.receate()** for the case you need.