# All activity with same attribute Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have many activity that has same attributes,

```
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.a" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.b" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.c" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.d" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.e" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.f" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.g" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.h" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
    <activity android:name="com.packagename.i" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
```

Is there any simple way to declare the attributes once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is doing this in a `BaseActivity` in Java code, and all other activities inherit this `BaseActivity`, but it seems those activity's attributes can not be applied programmatically. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245758/android-activity-how-to-override-manifests-androidconfigchanges-with-java-cod)

If you feel tedious of typing these attributes, I suggest you to utilize the editor to finish your job, such as XML code snippet or other methods.